# ITC.apps.assetvalidation.PURPLE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_BAD_PLIST.error.message

Tags: app-store-connect

What does this error mean in iTunes Connect when I am trying to submit an update to my app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug on Apple's end. Try waiting for a fix or creating a new provisioning profile. This has been raised in both of Apple's forums by the same person:

- https://devforums.apple.com/message/1065069
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6628827